# Is fixed width still responsive design?

Tags: css, responsive-design

Assuming a site is:

- Initially set up using a fixed width
- Adapts via media queries
- Looks great at various sizes

Is it still considered responsive, even though a flexible grid type layout is not involved?

Comment: Yes.  It is still considered responsive.

Comment: @Mash: Post that as an answer?

Comment: upvote considering that this is a conceptual question requiring definition to the user asking.

Comment: Hmmm, my questions always attract down votes and [close].  But still a 7204 and 26 gold badges  :)   Who are these people?  I'm glad some one posted a very good answer to an important question.  The question was basically yes or no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Responsive design" is really more of a marketing term than a scientific practice, and there is certainly no standard for it.  Whether or not a design is responsive is subject to opinion, but if it can be viewed optimally across a range of devices, most people would consider it "responsive."  In my opinion that is the single goal of a responsive design.  How it is achieved (including using fixed widths) is not important in light of the result.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  considering the upvotes on this answer, I think it is a very good definition.  But I see fluid grid everywhere when discussing responsive design, as if it is some kind of requirement for being responsive.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that designs are going to be challenged with more and more in the future is scaling up as well as down. This often affects width more than height. Think of all the big screen wide aspect laptops that have come out in the last few years. Also, TVs are being more and more tightly integrated with the web as time goes on.

So, would the design in question be responsive? Yes. Would it be **fully** responsive? No.

As mentioned, there is no standard for responsive design. Responsive design adds time to project and cost to budgets. You have to decide the cost/benefit ratio of the desired features and proceed from there to determine what feature set makes sense for your use case.

Comment: Not to complicate things but Ethan Marcotte always discusses fluid grid when he mentions responsive design.  He coined the term responsive design.  In that respect, it doesn't have anything to do with marketing.